# Add classes to cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, class, cocos2d-iphone

i have a class CCButton, how can i add it to my cocos2d library
so that i dont need to manualy add it my new projects
and it is automaticaly added in the cocos2d templates.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a wise idea - changing a fundamental framework can make your code not properly work if using source control like SVN or GIT.

Comment: just interesting, what does your button can do so specifical, that you want to add it to the framework? and you can just create your own repository of controls, that you will be able to add to your project. then simply add one more external to your project and you will get all your controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea here would be to create your own framework project that you can reference in all other dependent projects. That way you only have to update the code once and make the changes available in all child projects.

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/05/making-your-own-iphone-frameworks-in-xcode/